# aws transfer update-server is throwing errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli

I am using terraform to create an aws sftp server and trying to use [IP whitelisting](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/use-ip-whitelisting-to-secure-your-aws-transfer-for-sftp-servers/) to secure my server.

Terraform `aws_transfer_server` command supports only [endpoint_types](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/transfer_server#endpoint_type) such as PUBLIC or VPC_ENDPOINT at this time. So I am using `null_resource` to execute an aws command to update the sftp server after it was created. The terraform snippet is below:

```
resource "null_resource" "update_sftp_server" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
aws transfer update-server --server-id ${aws_transfer_server.sftp.id} --endpoint-type VPC --endpoint-details SubnetIds="${join("\", \"", var.subnet_ids)}", AddressAllocationIds="${join("\", \"", toset(aws_eip.nlb.*.id))}", VPCEndpointID="${aws_vpc_endpoint.transfer.id}", VpcId="${var.vpc_id}"
EOF
  }
  depends_on = [aws_transfer_server.sftp, aws_vpc_endpoint.transfer]
}
```

This executes the below aws command

```
aws transfer update-server --server-id s-######## --endpoint-type VPC --endpoint-details SubnetIds="subnet-#####", "subnet-#####", AddressAllocationIds="eipalloc-######", "eipalloc-######", VPCEndpointID="vpce-#######", VpcId="vpc-#####"
```

But I am getting an error as below:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: AddressAllocationIds=eipalloc-######, eipalloc-######, VPCEndpointID=vpce-######, VpcId=vpc-######, subnet-######
```

Can someone help me to know why this error is thrown? My environment details are below:

```
Terraform v0.12.28
provider.aws v3.0.0
provider.null v2.1.2
aws-cli/2.0.33 Python/3.7.7 Windows/10 botocore/2.0.0dev37
```

Comment: Have you tried building your argument list without spaces? So that it looks like `SubnetIds="subnet-#####","subnet-#####",AddressAllocationIds="eipalloc-######","eipalloc-######",VPCEndpointID="vpce-#######",VpcId="vpc-#####"` ?

Comment: @lxop: That worked. But now I am getting an error `An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the UpdateServer operation: Cannot specify AddressAllocationids when updating server to EndpointType: VPC`

Comment: Sounds like a separate question, but check that you have capitalised the `Ids` section of the property name - the error message suggests that you haven't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried building your argument list without spaces? So that it looks like `SubnetIds="subnet-#####","subnet-#####",AddressAllocationIds="eipalloc-######","eipalloc-######",VPCEndpointID="vpce-#######",VpcId="vpc-#####"` ?

Otherwise when the commandline is broken up into tokens, most of those bits will not be parsed as part of the `--endpoint-details` argument.