# How to convert a PUBLIC aws sftp server to VPC hosted using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli

I've already submitted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63604865/740756) with similar content. But since the first issue was different, I was told to create a separate question.

I already have an existing sftp server running which was created using terraform. It is having a PUBLIC endpoint and I want to convert that SFTP server to VPC Hosted with [IP whitelisting](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/use-ip-whitelisting-to-secure-your-aws-transfer-for-sftp-servers/) to secure my server.

Terraform `aws_transfer_server` command supports only [endpoint_types](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/transfer_server#endpoint_type) such as PUBLIC or VPC_ENDPOINT at this time. So I am using `null_resource` to execute an aws command to update the sftp server after it is created. The terraform snippet I planned to use is below:

```
//Existing command to create a public sftp server
resource "aws_transfer_server" "sftp" {
  identity_provider_type = "API_GATEWAY"
  url                    = aws_api_gateway_deployment.api.invoke_url
  logging_role           = aws_iamrole.log_role.arn
  invocation_role        = aws_iamrole.api_exec_role.arn  
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "transfer" {
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  service_name      = "com.amazonaws.${var.aws_region}.transfer.server"
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
  subnet_ids        = var.subnet_ids
  security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.sg.id
  ]
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.application}-${var.environment}-vpce"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "update_sftp_server" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
aws transfer update-server --server-id ${aws_transfer_server.sftp.id} --endpoint-type VPC --endpoint-details SubnetIds="${join("\",\"", var.subnet_ids)}",AddressAllocationIds="${join("\",\"", toset(aws_eip.nlb.*.id))}",VpcId="${var.vpc_id}"
EOF
  }
  depends_on = [aws_transfer_server.sftp, aws_vpc_endpoint.transfer]
}
```

The `null_resource` executes the below aws command

```
aws transfer update-server --server-id s-## --endpoint-type VPC --endpoint-details SubnetIds="subnet-##","subnet-##",AddressAllocationIds="eipalloc-##","eipalloc-##",VpcId="vpc-##"
```

This throws the below exception:

```
exit status 254. Output:
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the UpdateServer operation: Cannot specify AddressAllocationids when updating server to EndpointType: VPC
```

I see that if I remove the `AddressAllocationIds="${join("\",\"", toset(aws_eip.nlb.*.id))}"` from  the aws command, it works. But the Availability Zones mapping from subnet to Elastic IP does not happen as shown below: [image]

Once I converted this PUBLIC sftp server to VPC Hosted, I verified that I can run the command to include AddressAllocationIds separately after some time. But if I created another `null_resource` and tried to run the command, it gave me the same error. Can someone help me to achieve this?

My environment details are below:

```
Terraform v0.12.28
provider.aws v3.0.0
provider.null v2.1.2
aws-cli/2.0.33 Python/3.7.7 Windows/10 botocore/2.0.0dev37
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with AWS Support and they suggested to create a lambda function to do this as there is no easy way to do it at this point using a single aws cli command.

**Lambda function in python zipped and named as `update_sftp_to_vpc`**

```py
import json
import boto3
import time


def isNullOrWhiteSpace(str=None):
    return not str or str.isspace()


def isEmptyList(lst=[]):
    return not lst


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    transfer_client = boto3.client('transfer')

    subnetIds = event['subnetIds']
    allocationIds = event['allocationIds']
    vpcId = event['vpcId']
    serverId = event['serverId']

    if(isEmptyList(subnetIds) or isEmptyList(allocationIds) or isNullOrWhiteSpace(vpcId) or isNullOrWhiteSpace(serverId)):
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps('subnetIds or allocationIds or vpcId or serverId is empty')
        }
    else:
        print(
            f"Get the server details of server: {serverId} to confirm if the Server is already VPC and AddressAllocationIds exist")
        serverDetails = transfer_client.describe_server(ServerId=serverId)
        endpointType = serverDetails['Server']['EndpointType']
        if(endpointType.upper() == 'VPC'):
            existingAllocationIds = serverDetails['Server']['EndpointDetails']['AddressAllocationIds']
            if(allocationIds == existingAllocationIds):
                return {
                    'statusCode': 200,
                    'body': json.dumps(f"Server: {serverId} is already of type {endpointType} and with allocationIds: {existingAllocationIds}")
                }

        print(f"Make sure that the server: {serverId} is stopped")
        transfer_client.stop_server(ServerId=serverId)

        print(
            f"Get the server details of server: {serverId} and wait until the server is offline")
        serverDetails = transfer_client.describe_server(ServerId=serverId)
        while True:
            serverState = serverDetails['Server']['State']
            if(serverState.upper() == 'OFFLINE'):
                break
            print(
                f"Server: {serverId} state is {serverState}. Sleeping for 10 seconds until it is OFFLINE")
            time.sleep(10)
            serverDetails = transfer_client.describe_server(ServerId=serverId)

        endpointType = serverDetails['Server']['EndpointType']
        if(endpointType.upper() != 'VPC'):
            print(
                f"Update the server: {serverId} to a VPC Hosted without AllocationIds")
            transfer_client.update_server(
                EndpointDetails={
                    'SubnetIds': subnetIds,
                    'VpcId': vpcId
                },
                EndpointType='VPC',
                ServerId=serverId
            )

        print(
            f"Get the server: {serverId} details and wait until the server is now VPC Hosted")
        serverDetails = transfer_client.describe_server(ServerId=serverId)
        while True:
            endpointType = serverDetails['Server']['EndpointType']
            if(endpointType.upper() == 'VPC'):
                break
            print(
                f"Server: {serverId} state is {serverDetails['Server']['EndpointType']}. Sleeping for 10 seconds until it is VPC")
            time.sleep(10)
            serverDetails = transfer_client.describe_server(ServerId=serverId)

        print(f"Get server: {serverId} details again for vpc endpoint details")
        serverDetails = transfer_client.describe_server(ServerId=serverId)

        vpc_client = boto3.client('ec2')
        vpcEndpointId = serverDetails['Server']['EndpointDetails']['VpcEndpointId']
        vpcEndpointDetails = vpc_client.describe_vpc_endpoints(
            VpcEndpointIds=[vpcEndpointId],
            Filters=[
                {
                    'Name': 'vpc-endpoint-id',
                    'Values': [vpcEndpointId]
                },
            ])
        while True:
            currentVpcState = vpcEndpointDetails['VpcEndpoints'][0]['State']
            if(currentVpcState.lower() == 'available'):
                break
            print(
                f"VpcEndpointId: {vpcEndpointId} state is {currentVpcState}. Sleeping for 10 seconds until it is Available")
            time.sleep(10)
            vpcEndpointDetails = vpc_client.describe_vpc_endpoints(
                VpcEndpointIds=[vpcEndpointId],
                Filters=[
                    {
                        'Name': 'vpc-endpoint-id',
                        'Values': [vpcEndpointId]
                    },
                ])

        print(f"Update the server: {serverId} again with AddressAllocationIds")
        transfer_client.update_server(
            EndpointDetails={
                'AddressAllocationIds': allocationIds,
                'SubnetIds': subnetIds,
                'VpcId': vpcId
            },
            EndpointType='VPC',
            ServerId=serverId
        )

        print(f"Start the server: {serverId}")
        transfer_client.start_server(ServerId=serverId)

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(f"Sftp server {serverId} is converted to use the VpcId: {vpcId}")
        }
```

All I need to do then is to invoke the lambda function from my terraform like below.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "update_sftp_to_vpc" {
  function_name    = "update-sftp-to-vpc"
  description      = "Update sftp server to vpc hosted for IP Whitelisting"
  role             = alks_iamrole.update_server_lambda.arn
  runtime          = "python3.8"
  handler          = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  timeout          = "180" //Set to 3 mins. It may need to be revisited if the sftp server takes more time to stop
  filename         = "update_sftp_to_vpc.zip"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("update_sftp_to_vpc.zip")
}

data "aws_lambda_invocation" "update_public_sftp_server_to_vpc" {
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.update_sftp_to_vpc.function_name

  input      = <<JSON
{
  "serverId":"${aws_transfer_server.sftp.id}",
  "vpcId":"${var.vpc_id}",
  "subnetIds":${format("[\"%s\"]", join("\",\"", var.subnet_ids))},
  "allocationIds":${format("[\"%s\"]", join("\",\"", toset(aws_eip.nlb.*.id)))}
}
JSON
  depends_on = [aws_transfer_server.sftp, aws_lambda_function.update_sftp_to_vpc]
}
```